# Access Control Service and Multi-tenant application

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller, azure, appfabric, acs

I m building a multi-tenant mvc application hosted in windows azure.

I would like to leverage access control service to allow user to get authenticated thanks to google, facebook, live id etc...

I managed to get a simple authentication working with a postback url that is configured in the Relying Party Application Settings.

but in my scenario it is more like that:
client1.mydomain.com/login or client1.com/login will go to the the providers pages select let's say google then he will sign in and then he will be redirected to client1.mydomain.com/Admin or client1.com/Admin

how can I achive that for any clients? should I add a relying party application for each client? can it be done by code? Is it ok with facebook?

I would like also the admin panel to be in silverlight, once the client is authenticated will he remain authenticated in the silverlight app?

Thank you by advance for any help or links that can help.

Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions I would say yes to all.  Each application would have to be set up as a relying party. So you would need to configure your app to use WIF and point to your Azure ACS.

All of these scenarios are covered in the [Microsoft identity developer training kit.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c3e315fa-94e2-4028-99cb-904369f177c0)

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Thank you I downloaded the kit and it seems very rich.

I will try do to it with it. Thanks a lot